# I have two problems with magento

Tags: exception

I have two problem with Magento.

I can't upload image in to magento. The image upload button does not work.

And I also have problem with the exception buttons in `system/configuration/design/themes`. I try to put the mobile theme codes in exception. But the `exception` button does not work.

please can anybody help me?

Thanks 
Mark.D

Comment: please check the permission of folder and also refresh the cache

Comment: Where do i have to check the permission of folder?

Answer (score 2):

You have to cd to your magento root directory via terminal and check it using

ls -l

you will have something like that: http://screencloud.net/v/o4D3

in first column you can see folder permissions.

To fix the permissions, you can run the commands [from the magento wiki](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/groups/227/resetting_file_permissions):

```
find . -type f -exec chmod 644 {} ;
find . -type d -exec chmod 755 {} ;
chmod 550 pear
chmod 550 mage #for magento 1.5+
```